# Marketing Cloud disable URL after click on button

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

I created an email where we ask people to answer a question in the email with YES or NO. After clicking for instance on YES, a cloudpage will be loading ampscript and changes a field in Salesforce to YES. The cloudpage redirect directly to a thank you cloud page.

My question:
Is it possible to disable or expire the link of the button after clicking on it?

Comment: Could you find a solution to it ?

Comment: No i didn't....

Answer (score 0):

One way could be creating a data extension that upserts clicks from a certain email send when running an SQL query within in an  automation flow:

```
Select distinct
s.SubscriberKey,
e.JobID,
c.isunique as 'Clicks',
from [_sent] e
join [_click] c
on e.JobID = c.JobID and e.SubscriberID = c.SubscriberID 
where e.JobID like "JOBID HERE" 
and c.IsUnique = 1
```

Then within the top of the Cloud pages 'landing page', outside the HTML script, create a redirect that checks if the contact/subscriberkey is present in that data extension,

```
%%[
SET @TotalNumberOrders = 170
SET @UniqueIdentifier = QueryParameter('GUID')
SET @Email = QueryParameter('email')

set @exist = rowCount(LOOKUPROWS('DataExtensionOfClicks','GUID',@UniqueIdentifier))

IF @exist > 0 THEN 
  Redirect('https://AlreadyClicked.com')
ELSEIF @exist == 0 THEN
  Redirect('https://FreshNewClick.com')
ENDIF
]%%
```

This will check where the contact falls. Would need to be mindful or how frequent the data extension updates and when the next email is send.

Comment: I would encourage you to not use like with JobIDs when you already know them. Use '=' instead. Moreover " will most likely gonna crash you need to use ' in sql

Comment: Good point @JohannesSchapdick